# Will Page.ClientScript.GetWebResourceUrl work with Spark?

Tags: spark-view-engine

I'm working on converting NerdDinner to Spark and have everything except the mobile views (which I'm not worrying about) and some code that uses Page.  Here is one of the locations that is hanging up - but there are a couple of others due to the View not having a Page ...

In asp.net mvc the code looks like this:

```
<link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<%=Page.ClientScript.GetWebResourceUrl(typeof(DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.RelyingParty.OpenIdSelector), "DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.RelyingParty.OpenIdSelector.css")%>" />
```

The "Page.ClientScript.GetWebResourceUrl" call fails with an error about there not being a Page.  Is this true?

I've worked around this one with adding an action that will return the resource as a FileStreamResult ... but there is another call using an open auth library that has a constraint check for a Page object ... so it fails due to the same problem - and unless I hack that code, I can't seem to find away around it.  Is there anyway to get a Page in a Spark View?

Comment: I have the same sort of problem of not having a Page object with the Razor view engine too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my project that uses Spark I am retrieving resources by use of a handler.

In reference to the other call, no there is no Page.  A Page object is actually just a special HttpHandler that renders the markup to the response.  So since MVC uses a different handler to create the Controller and render the View, there is no Page handler.

I would think the Open Auth library needs to be updated to work better with MVC.

Comment: I agree, I totally believe its more of an issue with the library not the View engine.